# Exit a loop by entering a specific letter, c++

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, exit

I know similar questions have been asked before already, but mine is a little different.

In the questions I've found here, the loop was supposed to end after the used pressed a specific character or a number, etc in such a way that while writing the code one was able to assign that character to a variable.

For example, when in the loop we input non-negative numbers `cin>>a;` and the loop is supposed to end when we input a negative we just write `while(a >=0)` or if  the user is supposed to enter some words and we keep them in variable A and we write `cin>>A` and we want the loop to end when they input `s` we can simply write `while( A != 's')`

But my problem is more difficult.

The user is supposed to enter the values for the following variables:

`char operationcode; int b; int e;` and optional `int k;`

The user is supposed to input the value for `k` if `operationcode == 'm'` so I can deal with it with `if(operationcode == 'm') {cin>>k}` - Is that correct?

And the loop finishes when the user presses the key: `'e'`.

I have a few ideas how to this, but I want to make sure if I am right.

The first one is:

```
int main(){
char operationcode; int b, e, k;
char stop = ' ';

while(stop != 'e')
{
cin>>operationcode>>b>>e;

if(operationcode == 'm') cin>>k;
}
```

I know there is also the possibility of using `getch()` but I am supposed to use only `<iostream>` and nothing else. For `getch()` I need to `#include <conio.h>`.

Could you tell me if my idea is correct?

Comment: Do you ever assign `stop` anywhere in your loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `operationcode != stop` as the condition for the while loop, otherwise I don't see how the loop will stop.

Furthermore it will make more sense if you use do while loop:

```
int main(){
    char operationcode; int b, e, k;
    char stop = 'x';

    do {
        cin>>operationcode>>b>>e;

        if(operationcode == 'm') cin>>k;

        cout << "code:" << operationcode << "b:" << b << "e:" << e << "k:" << k << endl;
    } while(operationcode != stop);

    return 0;
}
```

Also note that since `cin >> operationcode >> b >> e` will trim white spaces, it's not a good idea to use a blankspace for detecting `stop`. I used `x` here instead.

Therefore now if you run the program, it should do this:

```
1 2 3 4
>> code:1b:2e:3k:0

m 1 2 3 4
>> code:1b:2e:3k:4

x 0 0 0 0
>> code:xb:0e:0k:0
```

Comment: Ok, so if I understood your solution correctly, the variable which would take the value `e` (or `x` as in your solution) is `operationcode`? Because it is the first variable to which we assign a value in the given line.

Comment: Yes that is correct, with this line ```cin>>operationcode>>b>>e```, at runtime the program will ask for an input, split the entire line of input based on whitespace characters and setting the variables accordingly. For example ```x[space][space]0[space]0[space][space][space]0[space]0``` will set ```operationcode``` to ```x```, ```b and e``` to 0 even if they have multiple white spaces. (I used [space] to indicate a space character)

Comment: Thank you a lot for taking the time to write up the answer. My mistake is quite embarrassing...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your loop. It checks for a character `stop` which you haven't even assigned.

So, the correct way here is

```
while(stop != 'e')
{
  //Not sure why you need 'em here.
  cin>>operationcode>>b>>e;

  if(operationcode == 'm') cin>>k;

 //assign stop here.
 cin>>stop
}
```